# C# Parse SqlDbType Conversion

Tags: c#, parsing, casting, type-conversion, sqldbtype

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
(SqlDbType.Int).Parse(dtbDataTable.Rows[0]["Id"])
```

Comment: What is the value of `dtbDataTable.Rows[0]["Id"]`?

Comment: Is "Id" actually a data type identifier, or are you trying to figure out the data of the column Id?

Comment: Can you explain why do you want to output the ["Id"] field to the enumeration of type SqlDbType?
Don't you want to do Int.Parse(dtbDataTable.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString()) or simply (int)dtbDataTable.Rows[0]["Id"] if this is already an integer?

Comment: It is not a typed DataTable, because it is dynamic...The Id constains a number like 150

Comment: @saamorim, i dont want to let the conversion error of any data occurs inside the stored procedure, because i wont know what column is in the wrong type, so i want to make the tryparse at setting time

Comment: @raddesso so do a If(Int.TryParse(dtbDataTable.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString(), out yourParsedId))

Comment: Right, but instead of use 'Int.TryParse', I want to use the SqlDbType.TryParse or something using GetType. Because the system datatypes are not the same of SqlDbType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting back my workaround:

```
    public static string ParseValue(SqlDbType psdtParameter, string pstrValue, string pstrDateFormat = null)
    {
        object objReturn = new object();
        if (pstrValue != "")
        {
            switch (psdtParameter.ToString())
            {
                case "BigInt":
                    objReturn = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Int64)).ConvertFromString(pstrValue);
                    break;
                case "Bit":
                    objReturn = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Boolean)).ConvertFromString(pstrValue);
                    break;
                case "NText":
                case "NVarChar":
                case "VarChar":
                case "NChar":
                case "Text":
                case "Char":
                    objReturn = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(String)).ConvertFromString(pstrValue);
                    break;
                case "SmallDateTime":
                case "DateTime":
                    objReturn = DateTime.ParseExact(pstrValue, pstrDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    //TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(DateTime)).ConvertFromString(pstrValue);
                    break;
                case "Money":
                case "SmallMoney":
                case "Decimal":
                    objReturn = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Decimal)).ConvertFromString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, pstrValue);
                    break;
                case "Float":
                    objReturn = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Double)).ConvertFromString(pstrValue);
                    break;
                case "Binary":
                case "VarBinary":
                case "Timestamp":
                case "Image":
                    objReturn = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Byte[])).ConvertFromString(pstrValue);
                    break;
                case "Int":
                    objReturn = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Int32)).ConvertFromString(pstrValue);
                    break;
                case "Real":
                    objReturn = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Single)).ConvertFromString(pstrValue);
                    break;
                case "SmallInt":
                    objReturn = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Int16)).ConvertFromString(pstrValue);
                    break;
                case "TinyInt":
                    objReturn = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Byte)).ConvertFromString(pstrValue);
                    break;
            }
            return objReturn.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. SqlDbType is an enum, so `(SqlDbType.Int)` actually boils down to an integer value, not a type. The only way I can think of to do this is some sort of switch statement:

```
switch (SqlDbType dbType)
{
    case SqlDbType.Int:
       int value = Int32.Parse(dtbDataTable.Rows[0]["Id"]);
       //Do stuff with this value
    //repeat for other types
 }
```

Comment: It is a nice way to solve my problem @Omada, i use it inside my Framework to another things, but it reduces a little of performance because of existing a lot of parameters sometimes

Comment: If exists some way of not doing the parse and the switch case, it would look better

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be tough to do, and it's not the most readable way. I handle this via extension methods to help with TinyInt, SmallInt, and nullable values across the board. E.g.:

```
using (var dr = new SafeDataReader(cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
  while (dr.Read()) {
   int? id = dr.GetNullableIntFromSqlTinyInt(0);
   // Other stuff like that to handle type conversions
  }
}
```

SafeDataReader is part of the CSLA business object framework, but you could implement your own DataReader if you would like. It's a lot more legible and encapsulates all the parsing logic behind the scenes to the extension method.

Comment: It is not applicable to Int only, there is various datatypes @Joe, this solution looks specific to Int/Tinyint types

Comment: This example yes, so you'd have a library of such extension methods of GetXFromSqlY(). We have about 15 or so of these.